# LibreOffice Fresh to LibreOffice Still

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice Fresh in my Ubuntu 16.10. Is there any way to switch from LibreOffice Fresh to LibreOffice Still? I think it's more stable.

Thank you!

Comment: Uninstall one, install the other?

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove "fresh" (and the PPA you used if you used a PPA) and then install the "stable" (or "still") version. If you use the normal installation methods.

"Stable" also has a different version than the version used in Ubuntu. We use the stable version as released when Ubuntu features got frozen; so a few days/weeks before the final release.

---

If you install both from source you can switch. Easy setup:

- put each of the Libreoffices into their own directory in /opt/
  For instance ...

  ```
  /opt/libreoffice-fresh/
  /opt/libreoffice-stable/
  ```

  (Add a versionnumber to the directory if you want more than these 2)
- Create a symlink from the executable to

  ```
  /opt/libreoffice
  ```

  and use that to start Libreoffice (ie. add this to your PATH or connect it to your normal libreoffice executable.
- Switching between the 2 is as simple as pointing the symlink to the other version.

---

As an alternative: Libreoffice also comes in [snap](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/snap/) versions. That way you can install 1 using "snap" and the other through the normal channel.

> Running the LibreOffice version installed as snap
>
> After installing, the version of LibreOffice installed via snap can be started with the command:
>
> ```
> /snap/bin/libreoffice
> ```
>
> Omitting the full path likely starts the version of LibreOffice installed by the distribution instead, if there is one.

Renaming the snap directory would allow for installing more than 1.

Comment: I got it installed by default by Ubuntu... Then, do I have both versions installed? Can I switch without unistall? Thanks!